# Delay mail delivery in exchange server

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server

I want to create a  delay in email delivery in exchange server(say by 3 minutes). I tried with settng transport rules,but a transport rule (action) which gave a delay could not be found,how can i create a custom transport rule which does this task.